# Positioning Header/Footer "in viewport" with large table in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a simple page layout done that will have a header area at the top of the page, a footer area at the bottom of the page, and a big table in the middle with lots of columns and lots of rows.  The table is often too big to fit on a viewport (width and/or height wise), so page scroll bars are almost always present (this is fine).

What I want is that the header and footer have a `max-width: 100%` css property applied so they take up 100% of the width of the viewport.  And then I want the header and footer to STAY in the viewport (horizontally) when the user scrolls the page to see the table.  The header and footer are fine where they are vertically, and I don't need or desire to "stick" them to the top or bottom of the viewport.  I just want it so when you scroll horizontally to the right, the header and footer stay in view instead of scrolling off the viewable area.

I really want a CSS solution, but if that is not possible, then a jQuery solution could work too.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2krgecb4/

In case the fiddle link breaks, here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
My Page Header Section
</div>
<table>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
</table>
<div class="footer">
My Page Footer Section
</div>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.header, .footer {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff9999;
  max-width: 100%;
}

td {
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #9999ff;
}
```

EDIT:  Maybe a better way to describe what I want is to say that I want the header/footer to be inline elements, locked to their position in the y-axis, but be "anchored" to the left side of the viewport.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/2krgecb4/1/

Comment: I had been hacking around and came up with something similar, but that isn't really what I need.  The header will vary in height from page to page and depending on how wide the viewport is.  So "fixing" the height isn't really an option.  I don't necessarily want the footer to always be visible either, just show it when you scroll all the way to the bottom (inline).

Comment: I had also tried something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2krgecb4/2/ .  This would work fine on a touch device, but is horrible for a mouse because you have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the document to be able to hit the horizontal scrollbar.  Another "close, but no cigar"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of research, I can't find any way to get what I want using pure CSS.  It looks like some client side scripting is the only way to make it work.

I made the header and footer `div` elements `position: relative;`.  This leaves the `div` inline and allows you to re-position it from where it would normally be.

```
#header, #footer {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff9999;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative; /* KEY PROPERTY CHANGE */
}

td {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9999ff;
}
```

Then use some scripting (jQuery) to modify the `left` position property when the viewport is scrolled.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#header').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft()
    });
    $('#footer').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft()
    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle if you want to see it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/2krgecb4/4/

Note: To make this work in my mobile browser, I had to disable zooming.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Still interested in a pure CSS solution if anyone has one!